# How to analysis dml from oracle dump file？

Tags: oracle, dml

```
exp system/tao file=/home/fangtao/oracle/exp_full.dmp full=y;
```

How can I get `DML` statement from file `exp_full.dmp`?

Comment: don't you know which db this `dmp file` belongs to? If so, why don't you import it back to `test or dev db` of that db?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I know this dump file  belongs to which db.I just want to use this dump file to get dml opration ,like insert,update,etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a datapump dumpfile to do that, then you can do:

```
impdp userid=\'/ as sysdba\' dumpfile=exp_full.dmp directory=my_directory full=y sqlfile=myfile.sql
```

then you have creation scripts for all object in the myfile.sql.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Through this way,I can only get ddl sql statements，not dml sql statements.

Comment: yes, there are non dml in a datapump file, data is stored as datablocks, this is much faster that doing millions of dml statements.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to get dml statements from exp_full.dmp or other file.Any method to complete it？

Comment: I just want to get dml statements from exp_full.dmp or other file.Any method to complete it？